# __bridge casts in C++ & Objective-C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, objective-c++

I'm trying to write a templated C++ wrapper around a block and don't fully understand the affect that `__bridge` will have in the following code:

```
#if defined(__OBJC__)
#define SAFE_BLOCK_COPY(...) ((__bridge __typeof(__VA_ARGS__))Block_copy((__bridge const void *)(__VA_ARGS__)))
#else
#define SAFE_BLOCK_COPY(Arg) Block_copy(Arg)
#endif

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct CppBlock<ReturnType(Args...)>
{
    typedef ReturnType (^BlockType)(Args...);

    BlockType block;

    CppBlock(BlockType inBlock) {
        block = SAFE_BLOCK_COPY(inBlock);
    }

    ~CppBlock() {
        Block_release(block);
    }

    ReturnType operator()(Args&&... args) const {
        return block(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}
```

I created the `SAFE_BLOCK_COPY` macro so the class can be used from both C++ & Objective-C++, as `__bridge` is unavailable to use directly from C++.

My question is:

What is the affect of adding `__bridge` in this macro when compiled for Objective-C++?  As far as I understand it, `(__bridge T)` is essentially equivalent to `static_cast<T>` as there's no transfer of ownership, so the code generated should be identical whether called from C++ or Objective-C.

Is there any issues with the class?  It will be used in a single project from both Objective-C and C++.

Comment: `__bridge` just suppress the warning and tells the compiler that you know what you are doing

Comment: You will not be able to use this macro in Objective-C, because you have C++ template there. You should add other implementation for `if !defined(__cplusplus)`

Comment: Thanks for the information, that's what I thought was happening.  So am I right in thinking that the class as compiled from Objective-C++ and C++ will behave identically?

I'm only planning on using this macro from C++ and Objective-C++ so shouldn't need an Objective-C safe alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If the Objective-C is using ARC (and I think you are because bridge casts I believe are only used in ARC), the memory management of Objective-C object pointer types, including block pointer types, is managed by ARC and you shouldn't be calling `Block_copy` or `Block_release` on them explicitly.

You should probably do something like this:

```
#if defined(__OBJC__)
#define SAFE_BLOCK_COPY(Arg) (Arg)
#else
#define SAFE_BLOCK_COPY(Arg) Block_copy(Arg)
#endif

#if defined(__OBJC__)
#define SAFE_BLOCK_RELEASE(Arg)
#else
#define SAFE_BLOCK_RELEASE(Arg) Block_release(Arg)
#endif
```

Comment: One of the reasons for this class is so I can store Objective-C blocks in `std::vectors` and wrap them as `std::functions`.  If I understand correctly, the macro in your answer doesn't guarantee the lifetime of the block.  I think I want to call `Block_copy` even in an Objective-C context.

Comment: @GScrivs: It does. When you assign to a strong variable of block type, ARC will do a copy.